# NGINX configuration for CORS and proper HTTPS rerouting

Tags: nginx

Hi I'm quite inexperienced with NGINX and am having difficulty understanding why things aren't working as expected. I'm trying to test an API that I made with a docker container, which is being run with the command: `docker run -d -v $(pwd):/app -p 8080:8000 --rm wiseeast/ya_bot`.

I'm able to make API requests with Postman at `http://ffpr.isi.edu:8080/api` with a POST request, but the same request on AJAX with javascript returns an apparently frequent `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.` error. I tried to bypass this by enabling CORS on my server by adding `add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;` because I have control over it but it didn't resolve the issue. Also what is bugging me is that with Postman I can make a successful POST request to `http://ffpr.isi.edu:8080/api` but not to `https://ffpr.isi.edu:8080/api`.

Also, I have a rerouting issue that I feel should be straightforward given what I've read but isn't working. I have a webpage properly rerouting `http://ffpr.isi.edu` to `https://ffpr.isi.edu` but the rest of the rerouting doesn't work. For instance `http://ffpr.isi.edu:5050/` loads through port 80 unsecurely and won't reroute to `https://ffpr.isi.edu:5050/`. On the other hand, `https://ffpr.isi.edu:5050/` won't open at all with a time out error.

Here is my full `nginx.conf` file:

```
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;


    upstream frontend {
        server 0.0.0.0:8000; 
    }

    upstream ased_api {
        server 0.0.0.0:5000; 
    }

    upstream ya_bot {
        server 0.0.0.0:8080; 
    }

    upstream yesand {
        server 0.0.0.0:5050; 
    }


    server {
        listen       80 default_server;
        listen       [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name  _;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

# Settings for a TLS enabled server.
#

    server {
        listen  443 ssl http2; 
        listen  [::]:443 ssl http2;
        server_name ffpr.isi.edu; 

        ssl_certificate "/etc/nginx/ssl/ffpr_isi_edu_cert.cer";
        ssl_certificate_key "/etc/nginx/ssl/ffpr_isi_edu.key";
        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
        ssl_session_timeout  10m;
        ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

    location / {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        proxy_pass      http://frontend; 
        proxy_redirect      off;
        proxy_set_header    Host $host; 
        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP $remote_addr; 
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    }

    location /api {
                proxy_pass              http://ased_api;
                proxy_redirect          off;
                proxy_set_header        Host $host;
                proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    }

    location /ya_bot {
                proxy_pass              http://ya_bot;
                proxy_redirect          off;
                proxy_set_header        Host $host;
                proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
                add_header      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
        }

    location /yesand {
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
                proxy_pass              http://yesand;
                proxy_redirect          off;
                proxy_set_header        Host $host;
                proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        }
    }



    server {
        listen       443 ssl http2 default_server;
        listen       [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
        server_name  _;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

        ssl_certificate "/etc/nginx/ssl/ffpr_isi_edu_cert.cer";
        ssl_certificate_key "/etc/nginx/ssl/ffpr_isi_edu.key";
        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
        ssl_session_timeout  10m;
        ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        location / {
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;
            location = /40x.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
        }
    }

}
```

I've been suffering with these issues for so long, any pointers are greatly appreciated!!

Comment: backends must have a route with method 'OPTIONS' to answer frontend requests for specific route, you're looking for an issues on NGINX, where you need to fix issues on apps. They is some "unsafe" way to enable CORS open to all on your app

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, the add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*'; on the proxy machine did not fix the problem.

However, setting the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header from the backend API as a response header did work. For example, You can run the following Go code on the backend API:

```
(*w).Header().Set(“Access-Control-Allow-Credentials”, “proxy-host-name”)
```

As for the redirect issue, you don’t need to use two separate server blocks, try this instead in the nginx.conf:

```
server {
    listen       80 default_server;
    listen       [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name  _;


    listen  443 ssl http2; 
    listen  [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name ffpr.isi.edu; 

    ssl_certificate "/etc/nginx/ssl/ffpr_isi_edu_cert.cer";
    ssl_certificate_key "/etc/nginx/ssl/ffpr_isi_edu.key";
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
    ssl_session_timeout  10m;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

   if ($scheme != https) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri
   }
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! I've replaced with your code and it seems though now http://ffpr.isi.edu:5050 and https://ffpr.isi.edu:5050 redirect to the same https link! The issue with CORS seems unresolved yet but I'm working on the backend api to add similar headers.